Why does whatsapp business php api deliver my template messages twice?
All the template messages that I post once will be received twice by the opposite user. I send messages through php API. I have two apps under one business account, and both are having the same problems.
My PHP curl code is:
$messageBody = 'Welcome and congratulations!! This message demonstrates your ability to send a WhatsApp message notification from the Cloud API, hosted by Meta. Thank you for taking the time to test with us.' ;

$template_array = array(
    "name" => $templateName, //
    "language" => '{ "code": "en_US" }', 
    //"components" => '' //for parameters
) ;

$text_arr = array(
    'preview_url' => 'false', 
    'body' => $messageBody
);

$fields = array(
    'messaging_product' => 'whatsapp',
    'recipient_type' => 'individual',
    'to' => 91 . $toMobile,
    'type' => 'template',
    'template' => $template_array,
    'type' => 'text',
    'text' => $text_arr

);


$headers = array( "Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken, "Content-Type: application/json", );

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields) );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
//print_r($response);
$jsonResult = curl_exec($curl) ;
$resultCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

echo $resultCode . ' - ' . $jsonResult ;

curl_close($curl);


Does the same happen when you create and execute a simple PHP script, which contains only the code you posted?

Yes, same happening.

Looking at your code again, I can see that you're executing the curl twice. Once inside your json_encode, and another time when defining $jsonResult. Either: 1) remove $response line altogether, or 2) remove $jsonResult line.

Brilliant :) that was the problem. Thank you @FiddlingAway
